# How do I output /etc/passwd and save it in a sorted file in assessc called users.txt

Tags: linux, terminal

I am able to run the command /etc/passwd but how do I save it as a text file in my folder assessc, what would the path be as it is a users folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following

```
cat /etc/passwd | sort >> /home/assessc/textfile
```

You need to replace the path with that of your folder

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: @Biffen thank you I did not know you could that with just sort

Answer (score 0):

Optimized version of the other answer:

```
sort -o /home/assessc/textfile /etc/passwd
```

no need to `cat` and redirection